# Flattening messy data across multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

In Column N-R I have SKUs (in some cases just one SKU and in some cases up to 5 SKUs in total). In column S and T are the corresponding EAN and ASIN for each SKU in that row.

For example, row 27 has SKUs 6666 and GB-MA97-3GFI and the associated EAN and ASIN for each these SKUs are in the same row but in column S and T (so 8032947864171  and B071WWK11X).

How can I flatten the data so that I end up with three simple columns SKU, EAN and ASIN?

I flattened column N but then got stuck in terms of how to move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=lambda(z,filter(z,index(z,,1)<>""))
   ({N2:N,S2:T;
    O2:O,S2:T;
    P2:P,S2:T;
    Q2:Q,S2:T;
    R2:R,S2:T})
```